MasonryList React Native onEndReached not triggering a response @react-native-seoul/masonry-list
I am using MasonryList from @react-native-seoul/masonry-list for an infinite scroll component.
But upon reaching the end of the list, the component doesn't seem to trigger the onEndReached functions.
enter image description here
import MasonryList from '@react-native-seoul/masonry-list';
import ProductCardV3 from 'components/Products/ProductCardV3';
import React, { ReactElement, useMemo } from 'react';
import { useInfiniteHits, useInstantSearch } from 'react-instantsearch-core';
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { colors } from 'utils/theme';

const MasonryListCards: React.FC<{
  HeaderComponent?: React.JSX.Element;
  backgroundColor?: string;
  rerender?: any;
  data?: any;
  loading?: boolean;
  ListEmptyComponent?: React.JSX.Element;
}> = ({
  HeaderComponent,
  backgroundColor,
  rerender,
  data,
  loading,
  ListEmptyComponent,
}) => {
  const { hits, isLastPage, showMore, results } = useInfiniteHits({
    escapeHTML: false,
  });
  const { status, indexUiState } = useInstantSearch();
  const [scrollIndex, setScrollIndex] = React.useState(1);

  const width = (Dimensions.get('screen').width - 32) / 2;

  const renderItem = useMemo(() => {
    return ({ item }: { item: any; index?: number }): ReactElement => {
      const height =
        width *
        ((item?.images?.[0]?.height || 1) / (item?.images?.[0]?.width || 1));

      return (
        <ProductCardV3
          width={width}
          item={item}
          height={height}
          isLoading={
            loading || status == 'loading' || status == 'stalled' || false
          }
        />
      );
    };
  }, [width, loading, status, indexUiState, scrollIndex]);

  const masonryList = useMemo(() => {
    return (
      <MasonryList
        ListHeaderComponent={HeaderComponent}
        data={(data || hits).slice(0, scrollIndex * 20)}
        loading={status == 'loading' || status == 'stalled'}
        keyExtractor={item => item.objectId}
        numColumns={2}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        //refreshing={isLoadingNext}
        // onRefresh={() => refetch({first: ITEM_CNT})}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.2}
        onEndReached={() => {
          console.log('end reached');
          setScrollIndex(prev => prev + 1);
        }}
        contentContainerStyle={{
          paddingHorizontal: 16,
          alignSelf: 'stretch',
          backgroundColor: backgroundColor || colors.gray[200],
        }}
        ListEmptyComponent={ListEmptyComponent}
        containerStyle={{
          backgroundColor: backgroundColor || 'white',
        }}
      />
    );
  }, [hits, rerender, data, indexUiState, scrollIndex]);

  return masonryList;
};

export default MasonryListCards;


I have tried nesting it inside other scrollviews and flatviews but the onEndReached prop doesn't seem to be available. So I am wondering if that because this is no longer a prop in scrollviews/flatviews, that it is not available in the MasonryList

should be inside a SafeAreaView check the example provided with the library
https://github.com/hyochan/react-native-masonry-list/blob/main/MasonryExample/src/App.tsx
